# Why does an inkjet printer use the color CMY cartridges to print black images?

Tags: printing, printer, images, colors, gimp

I have observed that when an image is present within a Word document (or PDF) along with plain black text and the *Color* option is selected for printing, certain printers tend to use the cyan, magenta, and yellow (CMY) cartridges to generate a black shade, even when the image comprises pure black color #000000. Conversely, the plain black text is printed using the black ink cartridge. It is unclear to me as to why the printer resorts to using the CMY cartridges to print black images. Furthermore, the image in question was modified in Gimp and converted to grayscale using "Hue Chroma" -100 Chroma. I use an Epson L6190.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_black answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Colour printers (inkjet or laser) use colour inks to print greys.

Colour printers use black in grey areas, in order to increase the printer's grey palette, i.e. the number of greys it can print. In images, even black may use some colour, to create a deeper black.

In general, colour inks are used whenever the printer is not asked to print black only.